# How do I get Google rich snippet and structure data working for my blogger blog?

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets, structured-data, blogger

I don't know much about html but I have once got my post on how to carry out some steps featured with Google rich snippet by editing the post in HTML using schema.org markup but later got some how-to errors from search console stating missing title and description. Not all the details given in the schema.org are applicable to my post and I also noticed the way the schema.org code were written doesn't match with the HTML style in the blogger post but somehow I managed to edit the code to match the post HTML style. The markup was applied to a section of the post which had a title "how to ...", a brief introduction after the title and a 4 numbers of step listed.

I don't know what criteria Google uses to determine what page get featured as rich snippet as since search console reported the error, the page no longer get the rich snippet again even though it's till rank in the first page.

I do see a lot of pages getting featured snippet on Google even when the content doesn't actually contains all the data described in schema.org for the category of that post. I don't know what criteria Google uses to select which page get featured.

Example is the page: https://www.google.com.ng/search?q=how+to+get+rich&oq=how+to+get&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j69i59j0l2.9615j0j7&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Does Google rich snippet actually work for blogger?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google can create rich snippets from data on any domain. It is up to Google to determine which snippets would be most relevant to the search query.

Adding structured data indeed helps, but Google is intelligent enough to scrape information and organize it even without it.

Have you used the Structured Data Testing Tool?

For that link you provided, I entered that URL into it and it output all kinds of information you can incorporate into your own content to help Google understand your content.

You can see the results here - https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikihow.com%2FGet-Rich

@type HowTo and @type Article are going to be your best bets for an instructional content page.

I'd also look into structured data with JSON-LD format as it can be added without having to worry about how it displays.